# PayPal payflow for half payment

Tags: wordpress, paypal, payflowpro, payflowlink

For my next project i have used PayFolw. But my functionality is that my client want that at the time of booking we have to collect $50.00 as a deposit amount and the rest of the amount will payed us before 10 days of start of service (auto debit).

for e.g.
 i have a buy service of $300 and i am booked this service on 30/05/2014 for next month date : 30/06/2014. now at the time of booking (i.e. on 30/05/2014 ) we have to collect $50 as deposit money. now i have unpaid amount is $250 ( $300 - $50). which is collected before 10 days of start of service means on 20/06/2014.

we have also take credit-card payments for same mechanism.

Is it possible to do this type of functionality.

for this we have used WordPress and gravity from plugin for payment.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to Gravity Forms documentation the PayPal Payments Pro Add-On includes Recurring billing functionality so it should be possible to create a Recurring Billing profile to fit your requirements. http://www.gravityforms.com/add-ons/paypal-payments-pro/